# how to add metatags in custom 404 page in gatsby using react helmet?

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

i have tried like this

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

<Helmet key="helmetTags">
<title>404 | page not found</title>
</Helmet>
```

but this is not working. is there any other way to do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add `meta` property?

```
<Helmet meta={[
  {
     name: `description`,
     content: `your description`,
  },
]}>
<title>404 | page not found</title>
</Helmet>
```

Comment: tried this one still not getting the tags

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet'
<Helmet>
<meta charSet="utf-8" />
<title>"payment page"</title>
<meta name = "description" content = "your description"/>
</Helmet>
```

I think adding the text inside inverted commas like this  `"404 | page not found"` and providing charSet info might do it

let me know if it doesnt work

Comment: can u try now after adding meta charset info

Comment: getting the title tag but text is not coming inside tag like this **<title data-react-helmet="true"></title>**

Comment: can u try adding that content inside the meta description, let me know if im understanding the requirement wrong